# no JREs installed in the workspace to start spring

Tags: java, maven

I try to run my first spring project. However, I am not familiar with maven also java run time environment setup...
**I can run in eclipse, but cannot run in vscode**
 I got the maven project(spring Boot2.2.2, Java11) from https://start.spring.io/
Then I open it in vscode in Windows10.
When I type `java -version` in my command line, it shows

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

And properties in pom.xml

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

How can I solve the warnings `the compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 14 is used`and `Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.8. There are no JREs install in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment`
I cannot successfully run `maven build`.

Comment: I run it on VSCode, but warning is still there. Is that due to later version Java.

Comment: Probably. Try changing those `1.8`'s to `11` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Uninstall jdk1.8 (not supported any more) .
2. Install adoptopenjdk14.

In maven file: edit 1.8 to 14 14.

Check if you have JAVA_HOME env variable available & set. Verify with java -version to ensure you have jdk14 in path

Also install Java Extension Pack (for development)

[image]

Comment: Install adoptopenjdk14. Make sure jdk1.8 is removed (not supported any more) .   edit in maven  1.8 to 14 <java.version>14</java.version>.

Comment: I edit ```<java.version>11</java.version>``` to 14, and no any warning.

Comment: I am not sure that I am right. Does 14 in ```<java.version>14</java.version>``` mean that I am going to use SE runtime environment(JRE) 14 and java version 14 to run this project.

Comment: When I type ```java -version``` in my PC, I get ```java version "1.8.0_251"```
```Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)```. Then when I edit in maven to any number greater than 14, I can successfully run this project and no warning,**even when I edit to 20 or 30.** **Why I am not supposed to edit to specific number here?** What does it mean when I edit to 30```<java.version>30</java.version>```(I choose Java 11 when I create project in https://start.spring.io/)

Comment: You are stuck in chicken=fist or or egg-first.  THe problem you have is simple environment parameter issue, the explanation for it requires lot of typing, and  not worth it.  The solution provided would help you figure out the reasoning after you do it chicken-or-egg fist?. (1) uninstall 1.8 msi , (2) install jdk14 by unziping and edit JDK_HOME to point to it, open a new shell , closeopen vscode , check java -version to show 14, (3) change buid.xml to have 14 - good to go.